# Find the image of $|z+1|=2$ under $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ where $z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the image of $|z+1|=2$ under $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ where $z \in \mathbb C$

**My attempt:**

Let $z = x + iy$

$\displaystyle |z+1|=2 \iff | (x + iy)+1|=2 \iff |(x+1) +iy|=2 \iff (x+1)^2 + y^2 = 4$

Let $w = u + iv$

Now let $\displaystyle w = \frac{1}{z}$ hence we have that \begin{align}z &= \frac{1}{w} \\ &= \frac{1}{u + iv} \\ &= \frac{u-iv}{u^2 + v^2} \\ &= \frac{u}{u^2 + v^2} + i \big( - \frac{v}{u^2 + v^2} \big)\end{align}

From which we can deduce that $\displaystyle x = \frac{u}{u^2 + v^2}$ and $\displaystyle y = - \frac{v}{u^2 + v^2}$

and thus $$\displaystyle \bigg(\frac{u}{u^2 + v^2} +1\bigg)^2 + \bigg(- \frac{v}{u^2 + v^2}\bigg)^2 = 4$$

This is where I am stuck. I keep on messing up the simplification. Can someone please show me how to simplify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Proceeding with your result**, 
$$
 \bigg(\frac{u}{u^2 + v^2} +1\bigg)^2 + \bigg(- \frac{v}{u^2 + v^2}\bigg)^2 = 4
$$ we get
$$
 \bigg(\frac{u}{u^2 + v^2}\bigg)^2+2\frac{u}{u^2 + v^2}+1 + \bigg(\frac{v}{u^2 + v^2}\bigg)^2 = 4
$$ or
$$
\frac{u^2}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}+ \frac{v^2}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}+\frac{2u}{u^2 + v^2}  = 3
\\$$$$
2u+1 = 3u^2+3v^2
$$ or, with a little algebra,

> $$
> \left(u-\frac13 \right)^2+v^2=\frac49
> $$

which is an easy set to identify.

Comment: Thank you! :). This makes perfect sense :). Just to make sure I understand correctly, from the second last equation, you completed the square and then found the final result of a circle in the $uv$-plane? :)

Comment: @DJS Exactly. Let me know if it is OK. Thanks!

Comment: It's perfect! :). Exactly what I was looking for. :). Thank you!

Comment: There was an error in completing the square--the radius of the circle should be 2/3.

Comment: @frakbak Thank you very much, I will fix it!

Comment: $1\mapsto 1$ and $-3\mapsto -1/3$, so the center of the circle has to be $1/3$ and the radius has to be $2/3$.

Comment: Yes, so the final value should be $4/9$, not $1/3$.  One gets the same result, in an almost wholly geometric way, through inversive geometry: see my solution.  However, not everyone is familiar with that approach, so it may not be suitable for homework problems.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, using inversive geometry: Observe that $f(z)$ almost produces the inversion of a figure, with respect to the unit circle; in fact, it produces the complex conjugate of the figure's inversion.  However, in our case, the circle $|z+1| = 2$ is already symmetric with respect to the real axis, so $f(z)$ will in fact produce the figure's inversion.

Now, note that our input circle is tangent to the unit circle at $z = 1$, so the input circle's inversion, our output circle, will also be tangent to the unit circle at $z = 1$, but "on the inside."  Since the input circle also intersects the real axis at $z = -3$, the output circle will intersect the real axis at $z = -1/3$, so the equation for the image must be

$$
\left|\, z-\frac{1}{3} \right| = \frac{2}{3}
$$

Comment: Pretty solution. I was just proceeding with the OP result. (+1)!

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Yours is a worthy solution!  I merely think it is useful for later readers to see a different approach to the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for this solution :). This is my first course in Complex Analysis, so we have not done this using inversive geometry yet :). Although I must admit your explanation is very well written and can be followed quite nicely despite not having covered this method yet :). Thank you! :)

Comment: @DJS: Inversive geometry is an approach to certain geometrical problems in general, not necessarily having to do with complex analysis (in fact, typically not).  For most mappings $f(z)$ and most pre-images, it would not have helped.  But this is a circle, mapped by something that is *almost* an inversion, and it is a useful property of such inversions that a circle maps to a circle, so it helps quite a bit in this particular case.